# Forgot Password Function not working since I install new theme on Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, porto-theme

I have an issue with Forgot Password function on Magento 2.2

When I configure the design theme to the theme default Luma, the forgot password function is working. That’s mean I can see the notification “If there is an account associated with admin@demo.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.” after submitting email and captcha.

Please see the screenshot: https://snipboard.io/vb6NHr.jpg

But when I switch the theme name to Porto Theme or Porto – Child Theme in Design Configuration, then I test the forgot password function, I don’t receive any notification and still in the same page after submitting email and recaptcha.

Please test the link: https://magdev3.novationtools.net.au/customer/account/forgotpassword/

Please let me know what the issue is. This is very critical. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this issue. For someone who wants to know the answer:

I have rewritten the forgotpassword.phtml from the default theme to the new theme. That file in the new theme missed the form action

$block->getBlockHtml('formkey')